# Fan capacitor replacement question

Tags: fans, capacitor

I have a pedestal fan, and the capacitor needs to be replaced.  Unfortunately, I cannot find a replacement online.

Here are the specs:

1. 2-wire
2. 5.5 uf +- 10/5 %
3. 250 VAC 50/60Hz
4. MAX TEMP 70 C
5. E166700 G

I found a close one on Amazon, and am wondering if I can substitute.

The specs are exactly the same as above, except instead of 5.5 uf, it is listed as 4.5 uf and the +- is 5%
E163532

If this cannot be used, can someone help with an appropriate replacement?  Thanks!

Comment: Fan capacitors have gotten hard to find. The 4.5 uf should work fine, but IIRC, the fan will run a little slower, as uf  controls delay between coil pairs charging.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the cap UF rating or micro farids are within 10% and the voltage is the same or higher it will usually work fine.
This is a bit smaller but it will probably work.

Mcm 2 wire ceiling fan 5,5uf 450 vac Ccb61. would be a better match
$8.50 on amazon square case 2 wire . Free shipping

You can go higher on the voltage but not lower than the peak to peak voltage
120v x 1.41 =170 as an absolute minimum  higher is better and will last longer.